# Insert into в sql

Tags: php, sql

Имеется вот такой простенький код

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Brand
    <input type="text" name="brand">
    Brand Categorie
    <input type="text" name="brand_categorie">
    <!-- Categorie
    <input type="text" name="categorie"> -->
    <input type="submit" value="Sxma to eta">
</form>
<?php $add = $connection->query('INSERT INTO brand_id (title,categorie_id)  VALUES ($_POST["brand"], $_POST["brand_categorie"]');

if($add){
    echo "succses";
}
else {
    echo "error";
}




 ?>
```

В чем проблема, почему не добавляется запись в бд? 
Если что $connection это отсюда.

```
    require_once "config.php";
$connection = mysqli_connect(
    $config['db']['server'],
    $config['db']['username'],
    $config['db']['password'],
    $config['db']['name']

    );

if($connection == false){

    echo "Не удалость подключится к базе данный! <br>";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

сам Бд 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что, программа говорит success ?  У вас скобка в запросе не закрыта

Comment: нет, говорит эррор, какая именна скобка?

Comment: вокруг значений

Comment: Закрыл, не в этом проблема была

Comment: вот так `$_POST["brand_categorie"])');`

Comment: Ну да, у вас переменные под одинарными скобками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

должно быть так:

```
<?php $add = $connection->query('INSERT INTO brand_id (title,categorie_id)  VALUES ("'. $_POST["brand"].'", '.$_POST["brand_categorie"].')');
```

1) не закрыта скобка

2) php не интерпретирует строки в одинарных кавычках, поэтому переменные надо из них выносить

Comment: Исправил, ошибка все еще остается.

Comment: @Hayko echo  $connection->error;

Comment: Пишу в первом инпуте IRK во втором 1.
Ошибка - 'Unknown column 'IRK' in 'field list'

Comment: раз у вас там текст, то еще поправил запрос

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо.